# wrong header referencing using \markboth{}{} for dictionary

Tags: dictionaries, header

I am trying to implement a dictionary template for my own dictionary and I have a hard time with getting the headers right.

In a lot of dictionaries, the header contains the first and the last entry on the page. In latex, this can be implemented for example by using \markboth and fancyhdr.

When using \markboth, the problem is that when the last paragraph (= one entry) of the page ends the page, the header of the relevant page and of the following page does not reference the right entries. The paragraph beginning the following page becomes the last entry of the previous page in the header, while the second paragraph of the following page appears as first entry in the header of the following page.

If last paragraph x of page l does not end page => no problem

else if last paragraph x of page l ends page => last entry in header of page l shows paragraph x+1 (of page l+1), first entry in header of page l+1 shows paragraph x+2

Below, I show the code of a dictionary template widely available on the internet, for which I added more entries to make to problem visible. Especially look at pages where an entry ends the page.

Apparently, adding for example \vfill to the last paragraph of the page solves the problem (for the relevant page), but I would like to be able to solve this problem in an automated way.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
% Dictionary    
% LaTeX Template    
% Version 1.0 (20/12/14)    
%    
% This template has been downloaded from:    
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com    
%    
% Original author:    
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com) inspired by a template by Marc Lavaud    
%    
% License:    
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)    
%    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS    
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article} % 10pt font size, A4 paper and two-sided margins    

\usepackage[top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3.7cm,right=4.7cm,columnsep=30pt]{geometry} % Document margins and spacings    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters    

\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font    

\usepackage{microtype} % Improves spacing    

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for splitting text into multiple columns    

\usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec} % Required for modifying section titles - bold, sans-serif, centered    

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for modifying headers and footers    
\fancyhead[L]{\textsf{\rightmark}} % Top left header    
\fancyhead[R]{\textsf{\leftmark}} % Top right header    
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.4pt} % Rule under the header    
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\textsf{\thepage}}} % Bottom center footer    
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.4pt} % Rule under the footer    
\pagestyle{fancy} % Use the custom headers and footers throughout the document    

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1}\ {(#2)}\ \textit{#3}\ $\bullet$\ {#4}}  % Defines the command to print each word on the page, \markboth{}{} prints the first word on the page in the top left header and the last word in the top right    

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

\begin{document}    

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
%   SECTION A    
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

\section*{A}    

\begin{multicols}{2}    

\entry{Aardvark}{ahrd-vahrk}{Noun}{A nocturnal badger-sized burrowing mammal of Africa, with long ears, a tubular snout, and a long extensible tongue, feeding on ants and termites. Also called antbear.}    

\entry{Abbreviated}{uh-bree-vee-ey-tid}{Adjective}{Constituting a shorter or smaller version of}    

\entry{Aberration}{ab-uh-rey-shuh n}{Noun}{The act of deviating from the ordinary, usual, or normal type.}    

\entry{Above}{uh-buhv}{Preposition}{In extended space over and not touching.}    

\entry{Academia}{ak-uh-dee-mee-uh}{Noun}{The environment or community concerned with the pursuit of research, education, and scholarship.}    

\entry{Accomplished}{uh-kom-plisht}{Adjective}{Completed; done; effected. Highly trained or skilled in a particular activity.}    

\entry{Acidophilic}{uh-sid-uh-fil-ik, as-i-duh-}{Adjective}{Biology: having an affinity for acid stains; eosinophilic. Ecology: thriving in or requiring an acid environment.}    

\entry{Adaptation}{ad-uh p-tey-shuh n}{Noun}{The action or process of adapting or being adapted. Biology: The process of change by which an organism or species becomes better suited to its environment}    

\entry{Adenine}{ad-n-in, -een, -ahyn}{Noun}{A compound which is one of the four constituent bases of nucleic acids. A purine derivative, it is paired with thymine in double-stranded DNA.}    

\entry{Adorable}{uh-dawr-uh-buh l}{Adjective}{Inspiring great affection or delight.}    

\entry{Advanced}{ad-vanst}{Adjective}{Far on or ahead in development or progress.}    

\entry{Aerial}{air-ee-uh l}{Noun}{A rod, wire, or other structure by which signals are transmitted or received as part of a radio or television transmission or receiving system.}    

\entry{Affordable}{uh-fawr-duh-buh l}{Adjective}{Believed to be within one's financial means.}    

\entry{Agnostic}{ag-nos-tik}{Noun}{A person who holds that the existence of the ultimate cause, as God, and the essential nature of things are unknown and unknowable, or that human knowledge is limited to experience.}    

\entry{Aioli}{ahy-oh-lee}{Noun}{Mayonnaise seasoned with garlic.}    

\entry{Alchemy}{al-kuh-mee}{Noun}{The medieval forerunner of chemistry, concerned with the transmutation of matter, in particular with attempts to convert base metals into gold or find a universal elixir.}    

\entry{Algebra}{al-juh-bruh}{Noun}{The part of mathematics in which letters and other general symbols are used to represent numbers and quantities in formulae and equations.}    

\entry{Amatol}{am-uh-tawl}{Noun}{A high explosive consisting of a mixture of TNT and ammonium nitrate.}    

\entry{Almanac}{awl-muh-nak}{Noun}{An annual publication containing a calendar for the coming year, the times of such events and phenomena}    

\entry{Animal}{an-uh-muh l}{Noun}{A living organism which feeds on organic matter, typically having specialized sense organs and nervous system and able to respond rapidly to stimuli.}    

\entry{Ascension}{auh-sen-shuh n}{Noun}{The action of rising to an important position or a higher level.}    

\entry{Aspire}{uh-spahyuh r}{Verb}{Direct one's hopes or ambitions towards achieving something.}    

\entry{Athlete}{ath-leet}{Noun}{a person trained or gifted in exercises or contests involving physical agility, stamina, or strength; a participant in a sport, exercise, or game requiring physical skill.}    

\entry{Azobenzene}{az-oh-ben-zeen}{Noun}{A synthetic crystalline organic compound used chiefly in dye manufacture.}    

\entry{Aardvark}{ahrd-vahrk}{Noun}{A nocturnal badger-sized burrowing mammal of Africa, with long ears, a tubular snout, and a long extensible tongue, feeding on ants and termites. Also called antbear.}    

\entry{Abbreviated}{uh-bree-vee-ey-tid}{Adjective}{Constituting a shorter or smaller version of}    

\entry{Aberration}{ab-uh-rey-shuh n}{Noun}{The act of deviating from the ordinary, usual, or normal type.}    

\entry{Above}{uh-buhv}{Preposition}{In extended space over and not touching.}    

\entry{Academia}{ak-uh-dee-mee-uh}{Noun}{The environment or community concerned with the pursuit of research, education, and scholarship.}    

\entry{Accomplished}{uh-kom-plisht}{Adjective}{Completed; done; effected. Highly trained or skilled in a particular activity.}    

\entry{Acidophilic}{uh-sid-uh-fil-ik, as-i-duh-}{Adjective}{Biology: having an affinity for acid stains; eosinophilic. Ecology: thriving in or requiring an acid environment.}    

\entry{Adaptation}{ad-uh p-tey-shuh n}{Noun}{The action or process of adapting or being adapted. Biology: The process of change by which an organism or species becomes better suited to its environment}    

\entry{Adenine}{ad-n-in, -een, -ahyn}{Noun}{A compound which is one of the four constituent bases of nucleic acids. A purine derivative, it is paired with thymine in double-stranded DNA.}    

\entry{Adorable}{uh-dawr-uh-buh l}{Adjective}{Inspiring great affection or delight.}    

\entry{Advanced}{ad-vanst}{Adjective}{Far on or ahead in development or progress.}    

\entry{Aerial}{air-ee-uh l}{Noun}{A rod, wire, or other structure by which signals are transmitted or received as part of a radio or television transmission or receiving system.}    

\entry{Affordable}{uh-fawr-duh-buh l}{Adjective}{Believed to be within one's financial means.}    

\entry{Agnostic}{ag-nos-tik}{Noun}{A person who holds that the existence of the ultimate cause, as God, and the essential nature of things are unknown and unknowable, or that human knowledge is limited to experience.}    

\entry{Aioli}{ahy-oh-lee}{Noun}{Mayonnaise seasoned with garlic.}    

\entry{Alchemy}{al-kuh-mee}{Noun}{The medieval forerunner of chemistry, concerned with the transmutation of matter, in particular with attempts to convert base metals into gold or find a universal elixir.}    

\entry{Algebra}{al-juh-bruh}{Noun}{The part of mathematics in which letters and other general symbols are used to represent numbers and quantities in formulae and equations.}    

\entry{Amatol}{am-uh-tawl}{Noun}{A high explosive consisting of a mixture of TNT and ammonium nitrate.}    

\entry{Almanac}{awl-muh-nak}{Noun}{An annual publication containing a calendar for the coming year, the times of such events and phenomena}    

\entry{Animal}{an-uh-muh l}{Noun}{A living organism which feeds on organic matter, typically having specialized sense organs and nervous system and able to respond rapidly to stimuli.}    

\entry{Ascension}{auh-sen-shuh n}{Noun}{The action of rising to an important position or a higher level.}    

\entry{Aspire}{uh-spahyuh r}{Verb}{Direct one's hopes or ambitions towards achieving something.}    

\entry{Athlete}{ath-leet}{Noun}{a person trained or gifted in exercises or contests involving physical agility, stamina, or strength; a participant in a sport, exercise, or game requiring physical skill.}    

\entry{Azobenzene}{az-oh-ben-zeen}{Noun}{A synthetic crystalline organic compound used chiefly in dye manufacture.}    

\entry{Aardvark}{ahrd-vahrk}{Noun}{A nocturnal badger-sized burrowing mammal of Africa, with long ears, a tubular snout, and a long extensible tongue, feeding on ants and termites. Also called antbear.}    

\entry{Abbreviated}{uh-bree-vee-ey-tid}{Adjective}{Constituting a shorter or smaller version of}    

\entry{Aberration}{ab-uh-rey-shuh n}{Noun}{The act of deviating from the ordinary, usual, or normal type.}    

\entry{Above}{uh-buhv}{Preposition}{In extended space over and not touching.}    

\entry{Academia}{ak-uh-dee-mee-uh}{Noun}{The environment or community concerned with the pursuit of research, education, and scholarship.}    

\entry{Accomplished}{uh-kom-plisht}{Adjective}{Completed; done; effected. Highly trained or skilled in a particular activity.}    

\entry{Acidophilic}{uh-sid-uh-fil-ik, as-i-duh-}{Adjective}{Biology: having an affinity for acid stains; eosinophilic. Ecology: thriving in or requiring an acid environment.}    

\entry{Adaptation}{ad-uh p-tey-shuh n}{Noun}{The action or process of adapting or being adapted. Biology: The process of change by which an organism or species becomes better suited to its environment}    

\entry{Adenine}{ad-n-in, -een, -ahyn}{Noun}{A compound which is one of the four constituent bases of nucleic acids. A purine derivative, it is paired with thymine in double-stranded DNA.}    

\entry{Adorable}{uh-dawr-uh-buh l}{Adjective}{Inspiring great affection or delight.}    

\entry{Advanced}{ad-vanst}{Adjective}{Far on or ahead in development or progress.}    

\entry{Aerial}{air-ee-uh l}{Noun}{A rod, wire, or other structure by which signals are transmitted or received as part of a radio or television transmission or receiving system.}    

\entry{Affordable}{uh-fawr-duh-buh l}{Adjective}{Believed to be within one's financial means.}    

\entry{Agnostic}{ag-nos-tik}{Noun}{A person who holds that the existence of the ultimate cause, as God, and the essential nature of things are unknown and unknowable, or that human knowledge is limited to experience.}    

\entry{Aioli}{ahy-oh-lee}{Noun}{Mayonnaise seasoned with garlic.}    

\entry{Alchemy}{al-kuh-mee}{Noun}{The medieval forerunner of chemistry, concerned with the transmutation of matter, in particular with attempts to convert base metals into gold or find a universal elixir.}    

\entry{Algebra}{al-juh-bruh}{Noun}{The part of mathematics in which letters and other general symbols are used to represent numbers and quantities in formulae and equations.}    

\entry{Amatol}{am-uh-tawl}{Noun}{A high explosive consisting of a mixture of TNT and ammonium nitrate.}    

\entry{Almanac}{awl-muh-nak}{Noun}{An annual publication containing a calendar for the coming year, the times of such events and phenomena}    

\entry{Animal}{an-uh-muh l}{Noun}{A living organism which feeds on organic matter, typically having specialized sense organs and nervous system and able to respond rapidly to stimuli.}    

\entry{Ascension}{auh-sen-shuh n}{Noun}{The action of rising to an important position or a higher level.}    

\entry{Aspire}{uh-spahyuh r}{Verb}{Direct one's hopes or ambitions towards achieving something.}    

\entry{Athlete}{ath-leet}{Noun}{a person trained or gifted in exercises or contests involving physical agility, stamina, or strength; a participant in a sport, exercise, or game requiring physical skill.}    

\entry{Azobenzene}{az-oh-ben-zeen}{Noun}{A synthetic crystalline organic compound used chiefly in dye manufacture.}    

\entry{Aardvark}{ahrd-vahrk}{Noun}{A nocturnal badger-sized burrowing mammal of Africa, with long ears, a tubular snout, and a long extensible tongue, feeding on ants and termites. Also called antbear.}    

\entry{Abbreviated}{uh-bree-vee-ey-tid}{Adjective}{Constituting a shorter or smaller version of}    

\entry{Aberration}{ab-uh-rey-shuh n}{Noun}{The act of deviating from the ordinary, usual, or normal type.}    

\entry{Above}{uh-buhv}{Preposition}{In extended space over and not touching.}    

\entry{Academia}{ak-uh-dee-mee-uh}{Noun}{The environment or community concerned with the pursuit of research, education, and scholarship.}    

\entry{Accomplished}{uh-kom-plisht}{Adjective}{Completed; done; effected. Highly trained or skilled in a particular activity.}    

\entry{Acidophilic}{uh-sid-uh-fil-ik, as-i-duh-}{Adjective}{Biology: having an affinity for acid stains; eosinophilic. Ecology: thriving in or requiring an acid environment.}    

\entry{Adaptation}{ad-uh p-tey-shuh n}{Noun}{The action or process of adapting or being adapted. Biology: The process of change by which an organism or species becomes better suited to its environment}    

\entry{Adenine}{ad-n-in, -een, -ahyn}{Noun}{A compound which is one of the four constituent bases of nucleic acids. A purine derivative, it is paired with thymine in double-stranded DNA.}    

\entry{Adorable}{uh-dawr-uh-buh l}{Adjective}{Inspiring great affection or delight.}    

\entry{Advanced}{ad-vanst}{Adjective}{Far on or ahead in development or progress.}    

\entry{Aerial}{air-ee-uh l}{Noun}{A rod, wire, or other structure by which signals are transmitted or received as part of a radio or television transmission or receiving system.}    

\entry{Affordable}{uh-fawr-duh-buh l}{Adjective}{Believed to be within one's financial means.}    

\entry{Agnostic}{ag-nos-tik}{Noun}{A person who holds that the existence of the ultimate cause, as God, and the essential nature of things are unknown and unknowable, or that human knowledge is limited to experience.}    

\entry{Aioli}{ahy-oh-lee}{Noun}{Mayonnaise seasoned with garlic.}    

\entry{Alchemy}{al-kuh-mee}{Noun}{The medieval forerunner of chemistry, concerned with the transmutation of matter, in particular with attempts to convert base metals into gold or find a universal elixir.}    

\entry{Algebra}{al-juh-bruh}{Noun}{The part of mathematics in which letters and other general symbols are used to represent numbers and quantities in formulae and equations.}    

\entry{Amatol}{am-uh-tawl}{Noun}{A high explosive consisting of a mixture of TNT and ammonium nitrate.}    

\entry{Almanac}{awl-muh-nak}{Noun}{An annual publication containing a calendar for the coming year, the times of such events and phenomena}    

\entry{Animal}{an-uh-muh l}{Noun}{A living organism which feeds on organic matter, typically having specialized sense organs and nervous system and able to respond rapidly to stimuli.}    

\entry{Ascension}{auh-sen-shuh n}{Noun}{The action of rising to an important position or a higher level.}    

\entry{Aspire}{uh-spahyuh r}{Verb}{Direct one's hopes or ambitions towards achieving something.}    

\entry{Athlete}{ath-leet}{Noun}{a person trained or gifted in exercises or contests involving physical agility, stamina, or strength; a participant in a sport, exercise, or game requiring physical skill.}    

\entry{Azobenzene}{az-oh-ben-zeen}{Noun}{A synthetic crystalline organic compound used chiefly in dye manufacture.}    

\entry{Aardvark}{ahrd-vahrk}{Noun}{A nocturnal badger-sized burrowing mammal of Africa, with long ears, a tubular snout, and a long extensible tongue, feeding on ants and termites. Also called antbear.}    

\entry{Abbreviated}{uh-bree-vee-ey-tid}{Adjective}{Constituting a shorter or smaller version of}    

\entry{Aberration}{ab-uh-rey-shuh n}{Noun}{The act of deviating from the ordinary, usual, or normal type.}    

\entry{Above}{uh-buhv}{Preposition}{In extended space over and not touching.}    

\entry{Academia}{ak-uh-dee-mee-uh}{Noun}{The environment or community concerned with the pursuit of research, education, and scholarship.}    

\entry{Accomplished}{uh-kom-plisht}{Adjective}{Completed; done; effected. Highly trained or skilled in a particular activity.}    

\entry{Acidophilic}{uh-sid-uh-fil-ik, as-i-duh-}{Adjective}{Biology: having an affinity for acid stains; eosinophilic. Ecology: thriving in or requiring an acid environment.}    

\entry{Adaptation}{ad-uh p-tey-shuh n}{Noun}{The action or process of adapting or being adapted. Biology: The process of change by which an organism or species becomes better suited to its environment}    

\entry{Adenine}{ad-n-in, -een, -ahyn}{Noun}{A compound which is one of the four constituent bases of nucleic acids. A purine derivative, it is paired with thymine in double-stranded DNA.}    

\entry{Adorable}{uh-dawr-uh-buh l}{Adjective}{Inspiring great affection or delight.}    

\entry{Advanced}{ad-vanst}{Adjective}{Far on or ahead in development or progress.}    

\entry{Aerial}{air-ee-uh l}{Noun}{A rod, wire, or other structure by which signals are transmitted or received as part of a radio or television transmission or receiving system.}    

\entry{Affordable}{uh-fawr-duh-buh l}{Adjective}{Believed to be within one's financial means.}    

\entry{Agnostic}{ag-nos-tik}{Noun}{A person who holds that the existence of the ultimate cause, as God, and the essential nature of things are unknown and unknowable, or that human knowledge is limited to experience.}    

\entry{Aioli}{ahy-oh-lee}{Noun}{Mayonnaise seasoned with garlic.}    

\entry{Alchemy}{al-kuh-mee}{Noun}{The medieval forerunner of chemistry, concerned with the transmutation of matter, in particular with attempts to convert base metals into gold or find a universal elixir.}    

\entry{Algebra}{al-juh-bruh}{Noun}{The part of mathematics in which letters and other general symbols are used to represent numbers and quantities in formulae and equations.}    

\entry{Amatol}{am-uh-tawl}{Noun}{A high explosive consisting of a mixture of TNT and ammonium nitrate.}    

\entry{Almanac}{awl-muh-nak}{Noun}{An annual publication containing a calendar for the coming year, the times of such events and phenomena}    

\entry{Animal}{an-uh-muh l}{Noun}{A living organism which feeds on organic matter, typically having specialized sense organs and nervous system and able to respond rapidly to stimuli.}    

\entry{Ascension}{auh-sen-shuh n}{Noun}{The action of rising to an important position or a higher level.}    

\entry{Aspire}{uh-spahyuh r}{Verb}{Direct one's hopes or ambitions towards achieving something.}    

\entry{Athlete}{ath-leet}{Noun}{a person trained or gifted in exercises or contests involving physical agility, stamina, or strength; a participant in a sport, exercise, or game requiring physical skill.}    

\entry{Azobenzene}{az-oh-ben-zeen}{Noun}{A synthetic crystalline organic compound used chiefly in dye manufacture.}    


\end{multicols}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't test now but try `\leavevmode ` before the markboth.

Comment: I tried it but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting the paragraph before the \markboth works fine for me. With

```
  \newcommand{\entry}[4]{\leavevmode\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1}\ {(#2)}\ \textit{#3}\ $\bullet$\ {#4}}
```

page 4 now looks like this:
[image]

Before I got this:
[image]

Comment: I retried it (properly) and it works fine now as wanted. Thank you a lot.